# jQuery After appending element break new line

Tags: jquery

When I use append method of jquery to append the elements of "Javascript" and "React", the HTML format is like this :

```
<div class="my-3 text-center">
              <span class="badge badge-primary">HTML</span>
              <span class="badge badge-success">CSS</span>
          <span class="badge badge-secondary">Javascript</span><span class="badge badge-info">React</span></div>
```

It causes bootstrap cannot run correctly, I think it caused by the two spans elements are in the same line, How can I fix it? In other words, how can I break line after appending a new element?

Yes, there is not any conflicts, but there is no space between "Javascript" and "React", I use jquery to append that two elements, but they are on the same line what I want is like this:

```
<div class="my-3 text-center">
              <span class="badge badge-primary">HTML</span>
              <span class="badge badge-success">CSS</span>
              <span class="badge badge-secondary">Javascript</span>
              <span class="badge badge-info">React</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your above HTML is perfectly valid, and will not cause any conflicts with Bootstrap. If you want them content to appear on a new line, either insert a `<br />` tag, or style it with CSS. I'm not quite sure what you're asking?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I update my problem